# How can I color text in GitHub's flavoured Markdown?

Tags: html, css, github, markdown

I am trying to color a block of text which needs to be included in an article in a Git repository which is accessible to people. I am trying to color a word to bring the desired effect. Is there a way to use CSS styles to color the text since GitHub doesn’t support the styles anymore?

Currently, I am using the code below which doesn’t work in GitHub.

```
<center> <h1>2014, The year of <span style="color:red">Red</span></h1> </center>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such feature available right now. An alternative could be to color it in blue using links:

```
# 2014, The year of [Blue](#)
```

That would create the following output:

> [image]

If you really want to have another color, another alternative is to use an image (e.g. [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhgo2.png)).

Then you can include it like below:

```
# 2014, The year of ![](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2864371/10368192/cad27ed0-6ddc-11e5-8150-4f9c14ab9602.png)
```

> [image]

Comment: How do you decide the color which you want to use?

Comment: The only issue with the second idea would be that there will be alignment issues right? So you image editing has to be intact!

Comment: @Abhishek093 I just changed the text color in browser developer tools and then I made a screenshot. And yes, it's tricky to align that image with the other text, but not impossible.

Comment: @Abhishek093 But currently there are no better solutions. See the edit. You have to let a little blank space on the top side, so it gets aligned correctly.

Comment: I used your method for now. Hoping github comes up with something much cleaner soon.

Comment: @Abhishek093 Yes, you can write them at `support@github.com`–they will note your request in their lists. :-)

Comment: If anyone else lands here 6 years later - there is _still_ no way to do this in Github flavored markdown...