# Background colors for text boxes in github markdown (e.g. red warning box)

Tags: github, markdown

I'm converting some documentation from HTML to github-flavored markdown. I have lots of reddish/pink warning boxes in the old documentation.

e.g.

```
div.warnbox { background-color:#fcc; border-left: 3px solid #f00; }

~~~~~~

<div class="warnbox">
   If you pass null as a parameter the world will end.
</div>
```

Is there any  way to do something similar in (github) markdown? So far I've been using quote boxes which don't come in assertive red:

```
> If you pass null as a parameter the world will end
```

I also saw an interesting solution where someone suggested using diff syntax code blocks:

````
```diff
- If you pass null as a parameter the world will end
```
````

But that has multiple problems (gray outline, fixed width font, '-' at the beginning of the line, etc)

Is there any way (even if hacky like the diff thing) to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color text in github's flavoured markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017115/how-to-color-text-in-githubs-flavoured-markdown)

Comment: That is for changing the text color only. I want the text to be black.

Comment: same principle applies... not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Changing colour is not possible at this time.

If you want to create info or warning boxes, you can do so as of May 2022.
You can use the accessible **note or warning blockquote in Markdown**

#### Input:

```
> **Note**
> This is a note

> **Warning**
> This is a warning
```

#### Output Image:

[image: screenshot of example text]

https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/16925

Answer (score 0):

You can create color text or background in a GitHub markdown file by using diff, to create red and green colors, as in the example:

```
+ Green Text
- Red Text
```

Where GitHub markdown file does not support color, even though HTML.